# Polymorphically reading JSON with Json4s and custom serializer

Tags: json, scala, serialization, json4s

I have the following class hierachy:

```
object Calendar {
  trait DayType
  case object Weekday extends DayType
  case object Weekend extends DayType
  case object Holiday extends DayType
}

trait Calendar {
  def dateType(date: LocalDate): Calendar.DayType
}

class ConstantCalendar(dayType: Calendar.DayType) extends Calendar {
  override def dateType(date: LocalDate) = dayType
}

case object DefaultCalendar extends ConstantCalendar(Calendar.Weekday)

case class WeekdaysCalendar(defaults: Array[Calendar.DayType]) extends Calendar {
  override def dateType(date: LocalDate) = defaults(date.getDayOfWeek - 1)
}

case class CustomCalendar(defaultCalendar: Calendar = DefaultCalendar,
                     dates: Map[LocalDate, Calendar.DayType] = Map.empty)
    extends Calendar {
  private def defaultType(date: LocalDate) = defaultCalendar.dateType(date)
  private val dateMap = dates.withDefault(defaultType)

  override def dateType(date: LocalDate) = dateMap(date)
}
```

I have defined the following serializers:

```
class JsonFormats(domainTypeHints: TypeHints,
                  domainCustomSerializers: List[Serializer[_]] = Nil,
                  domainFieldSerializers: List[(Class[_], FieldSerializer[_])] = Nil)
    extends DefaultFormats {
  override val typeHintFieldName = "type"
  override val typeHints         = domainTypeHints
  override val customSerializers = JodaTimeSerializers.all ++ domainCustomSerializers
  override val fieldSerializers  = domainFieldSerializers
}

class JsonCalendarSerializer extends CustomSerializer[CustomCalendar]( format => (
    {
      case JObject(JField("type", JString("CustomCalendar")) ::
                   JField("defaultCalendar", JString(defaultCalendar)) ::
                   JField("dates", dates) ::
                   Nil
                  ) =>
        CustomCalendar(defaultCalendar) // TODO dates
    },
    {
      case cal: CustomCalendar =>
        val dates = cal.dates.foldLeft(JObject()) { (memo, dt) =>
          dt match {
            case (d, t) => memo ~ (f"${d.getYear}%04d-${d.getMonthOfYear}%02d-${d.getDayOfMonth}%02d", t.toString)
          }
                                                  }
        ("type" -> "CustomCalendar") ~
        ("defaultCalendar" -> cal.defaultCalendar) ~
        ("dates" -> dates)
    }
    ))

implicit val jsonFormats = new JsonFormats(ShortTypeHints(List(Calendar.Weekday.getClass,
                                                               Calendar.Weekend.getClass,
                                                               Calendar.Holiday.getClass,
                                                               classOf[CustomCalendar])),
                                           new JsonCalendarSerializer :: Nil)
```

I had to create a custom Serializer to get around the fact that, in Json4s, Map keys have to be Strings.

I have a file that might contain the data for some Calendar, but I don't know beforehand which Calendar type it is.

When I try the following:

```
val cal = CustomCalendar("default", Map(new LocalDate(2013, 1, 1) -> Calendar.Holiday))
val ser = Serialization.write(cal)
val cal2: Calendar = Serialization.read(ser)
```

I get:

```
org.json4s.package$MappingException: Do not know how to deserialize 'CustomCalendar'
    at org.json4s.Extraction$ClassInstanceBuilder.org$json4s$Extraction$ClassInstanceBuilder$$mkWithTypeHint(Extraction.scala:444)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$ClassInstanceBuilder$$anonfun$result$6.apply(Extraction.scala:452)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$ClassInstanceBuilder$$anonfun$result$6.apply(Extraction.scala:450)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$.org$json4s$Extraction$$customOrElse(Extraction.scala:462)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$ClassInstanceBuilder.result(Extraction.scala:450)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$.extract(Extraction.scala:306)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$.extract(Extraction.scala:42)
    at org.json4s.ExtractableJsonAstNode.extract(ExtractableJsonAstNode.scala:21)
    at org.json4s.jackson.Serialization$.read(Serialization.scala:50)
```

So it seems that Json4s isn't able to find my serializer.

So... any hints? Either on how to get Json4s to serialize/deserialize Maps with non-String keys, or how to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I implemented the JsonCalendarSerializer as follows:

```
class JsonCalendarSerializer extends CustomSerializer[CustomCalendar]( format => (
    {
      case JObject(JField("defaults", JString(defaults)) ::
                   JField("dates", JObject(dateList)) ::
                   Nil
                  ) =>
        val dates = dateList map {
          case JField(dt, JString(t)) =>
            val tp = t match {
              case "Weekday" => Calendar.Weekday
              case "Weekend" => Calendar.Weekend
              case "Holiday" => Calendar.Holiday
            }

            (LocalDate.parse(dt), tp)
        }

        CustomCalendar(defaults, dates.toMap)
    },
    {
      case cal: CustomCalendar =>
        val dates = cal.dates.foldLeft(JObject()) { (memo, dt) =>
          dt match {
            case (d, t) => memo ~ (d.toString, t.toString)
          }
                                                  }
        (format.typeHintFieldName -> classOf[CustomCalendar].getSimpleName) ~
        ("defaults" -> cal.defaultCalendar) ~
        ("dates" -> dates)
    }
    ))
```

I removed the `JField("type"...)` from the deserializer and fixed the serializer to call `format.typeHintFieldName` and `classOf[CustomCalendar].getSimpleName`, and that seemed to fix the problem.